# Unable to merge into the trunk

Tags: git, xcode4.3

I made changes to my branch, and when I tried to merge the branch into the trunk (master), I got this error message:

[image]

I committed all my changes, but I'm still not able to merge. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you committed all local changes?

Comment: yes, otherwise Xcode wouldn't let me arrive to the stage where i choose the branch to merge with, what you mean by local changes? when i go to File\Source Control\Commit, i checked all file i can check than i commit, isn't this what i should do? Thanx :)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't really commit all your changes.  Git commit will only commit staged changes unless you use the -a option.

Comment: Hi, thanx for your reply, what should i do to commit all changes? thanx.

Comment: Your best bet may be to use git from the command line within the project directory where the .git directory exists.  Do a git status and see if there are uncommitted changes. .

Answer (score 0):

Open up terminal, go to the repository folder. The run:

```
git status
```

It should show unstaged changes. Add them manually or add all of them at once:

```
git add .
```

Then commit

```
git commit -m "Foo"
```